# Navigation stackNavigator with onSubmit function

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

Navigating to another screen and submitting information at the same time:
The `handleSubmit` method is below.

```
<View style={CreditRegStyle.button}>
      <Button
          style={CreditRegStyle.button}
          title="Sign Up!"
          onPress={this.handleSubmit}
       />
</View>
```

```
export default class CreditRegister extends Component  {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    console.log('value: ', value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the react-navigation module, you can submit your information inside the handleSubmit method and at the end of the method just call `this.props.navigation.navigate(...)` as mentionned here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop

Your code would be like this:

```
export default class CreditRegister extends Component  {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    try {
        await submitYourInformation(value);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }   
 
    this.props.navigation.navigate(screenName);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
```